# Modifying mempool with an external program

Tags: json-rpc, mempool, spam

- Is it possible to detect stamps/inscriptions/brc-20 txs from the rpc method `getrawmempool` with verbose true?
- Is it possible to develop a small external utility that could access and modify the mempool, if not via rpc then some other possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect stamps/inscriptions/brc-20 txs from the rpc method `getrawmempool` with verbose true?

Yes. You could write a tool which periodically dumps the mempool and inspects the transactions to try to determine whether they match particular patterns.

> Is it possible to develop a small external utility that could access and modify the mempool, if not via rpc then some other possible way?

No. Bitcoin Core does not have RPCs to directly manipulate the mempool, nor are there other ways to modify the mempool. There is no way to forcefully drop something from the mempool nor force something into the mempool.

Comment: thank you, ya figured can get witness data from getrawmempool verbose true option and then detect. 
Bummer on external util. Hopefully consensus is separated out as a binary and people have better clients in the future.

Comment: what is this for https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/26.0.0/rpc/blockchain/importmempool/ ?

Comment: Bitcoin Core can store a copy of its mempool to disk, primarily for the purpose of preserving the mempool between short shutdowns. `importmempool` allows such a copy to be loaded while Bitcoin Core is running. However, it does not blindly add everything to the mempool, nor can it be used to delete things. All transactions in the copy are validated as if they had just been received over the network. If the current mempool of the node contains transactions not in the copy, those transaction still remain in the mempool.

Comment: gotcha, ya saw it does XOR with existing mempool, good to know it does validate added txs